# git-completion.bash in .bashrc gives "env_parallel: Error: Your environment is too big."

Tags: bash, git, gnu-parallel, git-completion

When I load `git-completion.bash` in my `~/.bashrc`, I get this error with `env_parallel`:

```bash
bash: /usr/bin/perl: Elenco degli argomenti troppo lungo
env_parallel: Error: Your environment is too big.
env_parallel: Error: You can try 3 different approaches:
env_parallel: Error: 1. Run 'env_parallel --session' before you set
env_parallel: Error:    variables or define functions.
env_parallel: Error: 2. Use --env and only mention the names to copy.
env_parallel: Error: 3. Try running this in a clean environment once:
env_parallel: Error:      env_parallel --record-env
env_parallel: Error:    And then use '--env _'
env_parallel: Error: For details see: man env_parallel
```

If I put `env_parallel --session` right before `source ~/.git-completion.bash` in my `~/.bashrc`, I get this:

```bash
$ par echo hello ::: `seq 19` 
parallel: Error: Command line too long (124136 >= 64024) at input -18: 1
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Something else is wrong or at least seriously dubious if you think you want to launch massive parallel processing every time you launch a new shell instance.

Comment: There is a limit in every OS (you never mentioned what OS you are using!) on the size of the environment and the size of the command line. As you can see, the  maximum size of your command line is 64023, but I would be more concerned about the size of your environment. What did you put into it that it is so big! As a first rough check, do a `printenv|wc -c`

Comment: @user1934428 I'm on Linux. "_What did you put into it that it is so big_?" The issue seemed to crop up when I put [`__git_complete g __git_main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48013474/1429450) to make git completion work with my `alias g="git"` alias. `printenv | wc -c` returns 7674.

Comment: So your environment is not that big. This should not be a problem. But I now notice that the error message _Your environment is too big_ comes later, and **before** that, we already see _Elenco degli argomenti troppo lungo_, and this is somehow related to perl invoked from bash.   The main reason seems to be the command line length. Does the error occur every time you are using the `par` command? If so, do a `type -a par` and post what you see.

Comment: @user1934428 `$ type -a par`:
`par ha "env_parallel --bar" come alias`

Comment: So you are effectively doing a `env_parallel --bar echo hello ::: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19`. This raises two question: What is the purpose of the `--bar`? According to the [docs I found on the Net](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/env_parallel.html), this is not a valid option for `env_parallel`. But since you don't get an error message for this option, I wonder what you are really running here. So now do a `type -a env_parallel` to find out.

Comment: Here is another quick test you can do: Just do a `env_parallel` without any argument. You should either get a reasonable error message or no output at all.

Comment: @user1934428 `env_parallel` gives the `bash: /usr/bin/perl: Elenco degli argomenti troppo lungo` error unless I first run `env_parallel --session`.

Comment: So when you do a  `env_parallel --session` first, then you don't get an error message? How is it with your original, problematic command? If you record the environment via `... --sesssion`, does the error go away as well?

Comment: @user1934428 "_So when you do a `env_parallel --session` first, then you don't get an error message?_" Correct. "_How is it with your original, problematic command?_" I get the error in my OP. "_If you record the environment via `... --sesssion`_" What do you mean? How's that different from running `env_parallel --session`?

Comment: I've never used `env_parallel` myself, but in the code you posted, you placed `env_parallel --session` just before sourcing your completion script. I would record the environment just before executing the `par` command. If you look at the docs I linked to, there are several usage pattern for `env_parallel`, and I would either strictly follow these pattern, or if I want to get fancy, I would study the code of the `env_parallel` function and see what it really does.

Comment: Basically, a good test would be `env_parallel --session; env_parallel --bar echo :::: $(seq 19)`.  If this does not produce an error, you are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log is as normally.

Run this:

```
env_parallel --record-env
```

After this you can add `. env_parallel.bash` to your .bashrc.

What happens is that GNU Parallel will determine which variables and functions are defined. It will ignore these. I.e. you probably do not care if the `git-completion.bash` functions are not copied to a remote server, because you only use those interactively.

What you typically want is to have the functions and variables copied that you set *after* logging in. E.g.

```
myfunc() { echo "This will be copied$myvar$@"; }
myvar=", too"
env_parallel --env _ -S server myfunc ::: '!'
```

The list of names is stored in: `~/.parallel/ignored_vars`. You should feel free to edit that list.

See also: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/env_parallel.html

Comment: Thanks. I put `env_parallel --record-env` first in my `~/.bashrc` (before `alias`s and my user-defined functions) and then put `env_parallel --session` at the end, that way the git-completion functions are in `ignored_vars`.

Comment: Do you want the user defined functions and aliases to be exported to remote server? If not, you should move both the end. `--record_env` only makes sense if you use `--env _` and is only needed every time you change .bashrc - not at every login. But if it works for you, great: You are at most wasting a few CPU cycles.

Comment: "_Do you want the user defined functions and aliases to be exported to remote server?_" No, that's not necessary. "_If not, you should move both the end._" If I do that, I get: "`Unknown option: --record-env`
`env_parallel only works if it is a function.`"

Comment: Yes, you're right; I got rid of `env_parallel --record-env`, and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `~/.parallel/tmp/sshlogin/$(hostname)/linelen` to something greater than 124136.